# how to add total wasted days in my query mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

i have following query i want to count totalwasteddays please help me this. where i wrong in total line number. i am new in mongodb please help me this i am very thankful

`error in this line TotalWastedDays: { $add: $toInt:"$none",$toInt:"$fade",$toInt:"$Torn"  }`,

```
db.getCollection('campaigns').aggregate([
    { $match: { _id: ObjectId("5b49d08db8695590d4ea7204") } },
    { $project: { doc: "$$ROOT" } },
    { $unwind:  '$doc.assets' } ,
    { $project: { 
          assets: '$doc.assets',
          none: { $filter : { input: '$doc.assets.outdoor_tracking', as: 'outdoor_tracking', cond: { $eq: ['$$outdoor_tracking.issue_type','None'] } } },
          fade: { $filter : { input: '$doc.assets.outdoor_tracking', as: 'outdoor_tracking', cond: { $eq: ['$$outdoor_tracking.issue_type','Fade'] } } },
           Torn: { $filter : { input: '$doc.assets.outdoor_tracking', as: 'outdoor_tracking', cond: { $eq: ['$$outdoor_tracking.issue_type','Torn'] } } },
        } 
    },
    {
        $project: {
            assets:1,
            none: { $size: { "$ifNull": ["$none", []] } },
            fade: { $size: { "$ifNull": ["$fade", []] } },
            Torn: { $size: { "$ifNull": ["$Torn", []] } },


        },
            $project: {
            assets:1,
            none:1 ,
            fade:1 ,
            Torn:1 ,
            TotalWastedDays: { $add: $toInt:"$none",$toInt:"$fade",$toInt:"$Torn"  },

        }
    }
])
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Error: Line 26: Unexpected token :

Comment: when i add like this   TotalWastedDays: { $add:[ "$none", "$fade","$Torn" ]  },

Comment: its show me error errmsg" : "$add only supports numeric or date types, not array",

Comment: Try `{ $add: [{$toInt:"$none"},{$toInt:"$fade"},{$toInt:"$Torn"  }]}`

Comment: "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$toInt'",

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Answer (score 0):

Modify

> { $add: $toInt:"$none",$toInt:"$fade",$toInt:"$Torn"  }

To

> { $add: [{$toInt:"$none"},{$toInt:"$fade"},{$toInt:"$Torn"}]  }

Comment: "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$toInt'",